# How to order geom_col by the largest average proportion for a group and then plot a stacked bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have data that I would like to order by the highest average by a group and then plot them as a stacked bar. I have managed to do this by producing several dataframes, but it's verbose and I am wondering if there was a less verbose way of doing this?

```
set.seed(3)
   x <- rep(letters[1:5], 3)
fill <- rep(letters[24:26], 5)
   n <- runif(15, 0, 1)
  df <- data.frame(x, fill, n)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(percent = n/sum(n))

df3 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(fill) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(percent))  %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(desc(mean))

df3 <- df2[df2$fill == df3$fill[1], ] %>%
  arrange(desc(percent))
df$x <- factor(df$x, levels = df3$x)    

ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, fill = fill)) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill())
```

[image]

Comment: Why is `a` first here and not `b`? `b` has the "largest" proportion for b/y.

Comment: Because its only sorted on size of z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is necessarily better, but here's one approach that yields the same graph in your question:

```
df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(fill != "z", desc(pct)) %>%
  group_by(fill) %>%
  mutate(order = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(x, order), pct, fill = fill)) +
  geom_col()
```

Depending on what you are actually trying to compare, you may want to consider a different ordering or perhaps facets. For example, consider what happens when you choose to facet vs. stacking:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, pct, fill = fill)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ fill)
```

[image]

Update 2019-02-18 (per comments)
Updating to abstract away knowing `z` ahead of time. Ordering by `mean(pct)` for each `fill` followed by `pct`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) %>%
  group_by(fill) %>%
  mutate(mean_pct = mean(pct)) %>%
  arrange(desc(mean_pct), desc(pct)) %>%
  mutate(order = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(x, order), pct, fill = fill)) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, but not quite what I need as it requires you to know what the largest portion is beforehand (arrange(fill != 'z'.... ). For my case use stacking is preferable, but useful to have the stacking code too!

Comment: @DomBurns understood, however, this is a bit misleading, because if we were truly arranging by the largest portion in your example, `b-y` would be first correct? Not `a-z`?

Comment: yes thats true if you used the highgest value of any bar (e.g. here y*b). But in this case I want to order by the highest average fill value (e.g. here z).

Comment: @DomBurns got it. See my update. Again, probably not much better since you effectively have two groupings that you need to determine, but at least this is one pipeline instead of managing multiple `data.frames`.